# jQuery plugin to execute function on after last selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

What I want to do is make a jQuery plugin that doesn't need an html wrapper to find the elements I need and then execute a function.

The html:

```
<div class="tscroll someotherbg"></div>
<div class="tscroll somebg"></div>
<div class="tscroll dia-left"></div>
​
```

The javascript:

```
$(".tscroll").tScroll();
```

and collect all elements with the class "tscroll" and then do stuff with it. Right now it the "constructor" (for a lack of better words, I have an AS3 background) gets run 3 times.

Maybe this fiddle will enlighten you a bit more: http://jsfiddle.net/summer/kN9nb/6/
(warning three alerts coming up)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plugin working per element so when you run `$(".tscroll").tScroll();` init will run for each element that will have "tscroll" class.
Change logic of your plugin, make it like function:

```
$.tScroll("tscroll");
```

So this function will run once and you will have class that will help you to find needed elements. Then in init you will make

```
$(".tscroll").each(function (i, object){
    //your code per element here
});
```